# VBA - Copy rows from a sheet X to a sheet Y if rows doesn't already exists, based on column A and column C

Tags: excel, vba, copy, compare, rows

I'm trying to do this code for a while now but with no success so far. I would like to copy rows from a sheet X to the end of another sheet Y if rows doesn't already exists in the sheet Y, based on a comparison of the data in columns A and C.

I already did the code when I just needed to compare with one column, and it worked perfectly. I put it just right there so you can see :

```
sourceLastRow = ws_src.Cells(ws_src.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
destLastRow = ws_dest.Cells(ws_dest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    For Each rng In ws_src.Range("A2:A" & sourceLastRow)
        Set foundVal = ws_dest.Range("A2:A" & destLastRow).Find(rng, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        
        If foundVal Is Nothing Then

            rng.EntireRow.Copy
            ws_dest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
              
        End If
    Next rng
```

Unfortunately, when I tried to compare two columns I don't get the results I need. I tried the code below but it copy the first row of my first sheet without stopping :

```
Dim ws_src As Worksheet
Dim ws_dest As Worksheet

Dim rw_src As Range
Dim rw_dest As Range

Set ws_src = Worksheets(1)
Set ws_dest = Worksheets(2)

For Each rw_src In ws_src.Rows

    For Each rw_dest In ws_dest.Rows
        If ws_src.Cells(rw_src.row, 1).Value = ws_dest.Cells(rw_dest.row, 1).Value And ws_src.Cells(rw_src.row, 3).Value = ws_dest.Cells(rw_dest.row, 3).Value Then
        Else: rw_src.EntireRow.Copy
            ws_dest.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next rw_dest
Next rw_src
```

Thank you for your time !

Léa

Comment: You mentione `A and C` and not `A OR C`. You want both conditions to be true. So your 1st code is good enough. Or have I not understood your query correctly?

Comment: Do you also know that you can fasten the entire process by using `AutoFilter`?

Comment: Hi, I want A and C to be true, and my first code only look at the column A. Sometimes I can have the same number in column A (ex : 12345), but if it's not the same data in column C, I would like the rows to be copied.

Comment: No, I didn't know about "AutoFilter", I'm quite new to VBA so I'm really open to any suggestion !

Comment: Ok first things first. If A **AND** C; both are not found then copy the row? If only A is found **OR** C is found then copy?

Comment: Yes @SiddharthRout, you summarize it right !

Comment: Ok one moment. Posting a solution using autofilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws_src As Worksheet
    Dim ws_dest As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set ws_src = Sheet1
    Set ws_dest = Sheet2
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    '~~> Find Last row in ws_src
    With ws_src
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    Dim rngToCopy As Range, FilteredRange As Range
    Dim NewRow As Long
    
    With ws_dest
        '~~> Find Last row in ws_dest
        NewRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lRow
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            
            '~~> Put the filters
            .Range("A1:C" & NewRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & ws_src.Cells(i, 1).Value2
            .Range("A1:C" & NewRow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=" & ws_src.Cells(i, 3).Value2

            Set FilteredRange = .Range("A1:C" & NewRow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
            
            '~~> If no match found then store the row in an object
            If Application.CountA(FilteredRange) = 0 Then
                If rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngToCopy = ws_src.Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set rngToCopy = Union(rngToCopy, ws_src.Rows(i))
                End If
            Else
                Set FilteredRange = Nothing
            End If
        Next i
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    
    '~~> Do the copy in one go
    If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then rngToCopy.Copy ws_dest.Rows(NewRow + 1)
End Sub
```

**Important Tip**: Whatever method that you follow, whether it is `.Find` or `.Autofilter` or anything else, do not copy and paste in the loop. It will be very slow. Do the copying in the end as shown above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the tip ! However it worked if the data are not the same in column C, but it doesn't take the row if it's not the same in column A..

Comment: sorry i did not understand.

Comment: Sorry, if data are the same in column C, but not in column A, I would like to copy row. But  right now the code only copy the row if data are not the same in column C.

Comment: Oh no, sorry, it worked ! I was just that it didn't start at the first row, but it's OK now ! Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple sample of what you are looking for. Modify the code to fit your needs and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowSource As Long, LastRowDestination As Long
    Dim i As Long, y As Long
    Dim Value_1 As String, Value_2 As String
    Dim ValueExists As Boolean
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsSource = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set wsDestination = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
    End With
    
    With wsSource
    
        'Find the last row of Column A, wsSource
        LastRowSource = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        'Loop Column A, wsSource
        For i = 1 To LastRowSource
        
            'Let's say we are testing Columns A & B
            Value_1 = .Range("A" & i).Value
            Value_2 = .Range("B" & i).Value
            
            ValueExists = False
            
            With wsDestination
            
                'Find the last row of Column A, wsDestination
                LastRowDestination = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                
                'Loop Column A, wsDestination
                For y = 1 To LastRowDestination
                
                    If .Range("A" & y).Value = Value_1 And .Range("B" & y).Value = Value_2 Then
                        ValueExists = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    
                Next y
                
                'if value does not exist copy
                If ValueExists = False Then
                    .Range("A" & LastRowDestination + 1).Value = Value_1
                    .Range("B" & LastRowDestination + 1).Value = Value_2
                End If
                
            End With
            
        Next i
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I try to modify the code to fit my needs, but I still got 1 problem : It doesn't copy the entire row, only the value on column A & C..

Comment: The code from Siddharth Rout worked, so my problem is solved, thank you for your help !